# MySql search efficiency

Tags: mysql, count, inner-join, large-data-volumes

So I am trying to get some geographical data at the moment from the some 34 thousand records we have.

We stored a records of Person, which include the basics like firstname, surname, address and postcode.

I am wanting to get information about the postcode, and link it with their Longitue and Latitude co-ordinates.
For this, i also have a table with australian postcodes, and their Long/Lat coords.

```
SELECT count(p.postcode) AS `count`, p.postcode, pctlt.Lat, pctlt.`Long`
FROM person AS p
INNER JOIN pcodetolonglat AS pctlt ON pctlt.Pcode = p.postcode
WHERE length(p.postcode)=4
GROUP BY p.postcode
```

currently, this script takes between one too two minutes to run,

Is there a more efficient way to get the same results?

Comment: Because I want to count the number of 'Persons' who 'lives' in a postcode, and I want to know the 'Long/Lat' Co-ords for each postcode For example: 68 records in postcode 2148, Lat:-33.78 Long: 150.87

Comment: I am thinking getting the results of the postcode count first in Person table like "select count(*) 'count, postcode from person group by postcode" and then join the result to pcodetolonglat table to get lat and long.

Comment: Do you have indexes on `Pcode` and `postcode`?

Comment: Which table is bigger, `person` or `pcodetolonglat`? If `person` is bigger, it might help to do `WHERE length(pctlt.postcode) = 4`.

Comment: postcode has a person_id reference, Pcode does not, 

Person has about 35k records, and about 20 columns, pcodetolonglat has  16.7 k and 12 columns.

The reason i have the length operation on the person postcode is because data stored is not 100% consistent, and i dont want information that isn't a postcode. (also some postcode seem to be foreign or not postcodes at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT count(p.postcode) AS `count`, p.postcode, pctlt.Lat, pctlt.`Long`
FROM person p INNER JOIN
     pcodetolonglat pctlt
     ON pctlt.Pcode = p.postcode
WHERE length(p.postcode) = 4
GROUP BY p.postcode;
```

You cannot do much with indexes on this query.  An index on `person(postcode)` should help.  That is the first thing to try.  The following is rewrite of your query that eliminates the outer aggregation, replacing it with a subquery:

```
SELECT pctlt.Pcode, pctlt.Lat, pctlt.`Long`,
       (select count(*) from person p where pctlt.Pcode = p.postcode) as `count`
FROM pcodetolonglat pctlt 
WHERE length(pctlt.Pcode) = 4 and
      exists (select 1 from person p where pctlt.Pcode = p.postcode);
```

The `exists` clause is to mimic the effect of the `inner join`.

With an index on `person(postcode)` this query may run faster than the original.  I don't like replacing `group by` with correlated subqueries, but in MySQL it sometimes has better performance.

Comment: Your Solution here was a lot faster, how ever with 16k different postcode, this gives me approx 15k useless results, as I need too feed the results of this query into another algorithm, I'm only wanting results with a count of at least 1.

Comment: Thank you for the update.
I understand how using an index would be a lot more beneficial for this reason, and after this thread I believe a slight restructure and clean up of the 35k records would be to referent postal code id's instead of postcodes them self would be a more efficient process.